# This webpage has a redirect loop - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter, twitter-gem

I'm trying to get my app to redirect to a custom route when it encounters the error:

`Twitter::Error::TooManyRequests`

However, I'm having difficulty for some reason and i keep getting this error:

`This webpage has a redirect loop`

Here's my controller:

```
#app/controllers/tweets_controller.rb

rescue_from Twitter::Error::TooManyRequests, with: :too_many_requests

    def too_many_requests

        redirect_to too_many_requests_path

    end
```

Here's my routes:

```
#config/routes.rb

get "/too_many_requests", to: "tweets#too_many_requests", as: :too_many_requests
```

I have a view within `app/views/tweets` named `too_many_requests.html.erb`

I know i must be doing something incorrectly but can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: Presumably your `too_many_requests.html.erb` has your twitter feed on it somewhere.

Comment: that's what i thought but `too_many_requests.html.erb` is currently empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, it looks like you redirect the action to itself:

```
def too_many_requests
  # Error handling.....

  # You should redirect this elsewhere
  redirect_to some_other_path
end
```

Comment: doh! you're right, silly me, thanks for taking a look